# SQL Server MCSA Database Administration Certification retires on June 30, 2020 - is there going to be a replacement?

Tags: sql-server, certificate

Looking at exams [70-764](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-764.aspx) and [70-765](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-765.aspx)

> This exam retires on June 30, 2020. A replacement exam may be available. To learn more, visit our blog: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/community.aspx and review our Exam Retirement posts.

- [Updated competency exams and certifications for 2020](https://assetsprod.microsoft.com/updated-competency-exams-and-certifications.pdf) (pdf)
- [Microsoft Certified: Azure Data Engineer Associate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/certifications/azure-data-engineer)

Is there going to be a SQL Server specific replacement for exams 70-764 and 70-765?

Am I getting it wrong, or this thing "Microsoft Certified: Azure Data Engineer Associate" going to replace "MCSA SQL Server 2016"?

If true, that is a shame, because it looks like passing its exams (DP-200 and DP-201) would require learning a lot of stuff that I actually do not need...

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/community-blog-post.aspx?BlogId=8&Id=375286 has the mapping for the current certs to the new world order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are focused on DB administration I would rather recommend certification "Microsoft Certified: Azure Database Administrator Associate"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/certifications/azure-database-administrator-associate

This one requires DP-300 exam and it is focused on Azure and on-perm administration.